# Copy terminal output to Mac clipboard?

Tags: macos, terminal, clipboard, stdout

I need to directly copy the terminal stdout to the clipboard on Mac. How would I do this?

Example:

`echo sometext | copy_to_clipboard`

or

`echo sometext > /private/clipboard.txt`

Comment: I am interested to know if it is possible to do this when ssh'ed to another box as well http://superuser.com/questions/405491/how-can-i-copy-the-output-from-a-remote-command-into-the-local-clipboard

Answer (score 34):

Use `pbcopy`:

```
echo foo | pbcopy
```

Also see `man pbcopy` for info on it and `pbpaste`.

Comment: Or for a file, e.g. rsa key use pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: But what if you SSH into some say Linux box and pbcopy is a local utility on the Mac?