# How can I copy the output from a remote command into the local clipboard?

Tags: linux, ssh, display, clipboard, iterm

I use `iTerm2` as my terminal client in Mac OS X. On the local system I can use `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to transfer data between the system clipboard and the terminal, but of course this doesn't work when you're ssh'ed to another machine.

Is there some way which I can take the result of a command and copy it to the clipboard automatically? Perhaps an applescript to grab the text on the `iTerm` windows, then get the next to last line?

For instance, if I wanted to copy the current working directory:

[image: Picture-48.png]

I run `pwd`, then use the mouse to select the text, and then press `command + c`.

Is there any better / faster / automatic way of doing this? I'm not looking for a bulletproof solution that would work for every command (eg: might not work when there is a huge scrollback) - I'm just looking for something to make this task that I do quite often a little less tedious.

**Update**

I'm looking into using `screen` to do this, but I'm still not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just tried this and it works:

```
echo "foo" | tee | ssh YourUsername@your.ssh.client.host pbcopy
```

Notes:

- I'm using `echo "foo"` as a stand-in for the command whose output you want to copy to your `ssh` client machine.
- I'm using `tee` so you can see it right in your terminal window instead of having it all swallowed up by the `ssh` command.
- By giving `ssh` a command to run, it will send the `stdin` that `ssh` received to that command on that other host, and then immediately return.

You could probably alias it to something simpler to type.  And be sure to use `ssh` keys instead of password-based authentication to save yourself having to retype your password. **Update:** And you can use [SSH Agent Forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) so you don't have to put credentials to access your local machine on the remote box.

*(NB: I'm not sure how well pbcopy/pbpaste work when you only have an ssh/tty/shell session and no Mac OS X GUI context. I think the pasteboard is a NeXTStep/Cocoa/Aqua/GUI concept, not necessarily something that exits at the Unix layer without the GUI layer.)*

When I first came up with this it seemed hackish, but the more I play around with it the more I like it.

Comment: This does look like one way to accomplish this (+1), but I don't really like the idea of having credentials to access my local machine stored on a remote box that I'm working on. That's why I was thinking of doing it more as a screen-grab. Can you think of any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: @cwd You can use [SSH Agent Forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd) so you don't have to put credentials to access your local machine on the remote box.

Comment: the article describe the concept OK but I guess I still need to figure out the commands to make that happen. Also I found this: http://blog.roseman.org.uk/tag/iterm2.html which looks promising

Answer (score 1):

**Simplistic solution**

On your ssh remote.host create `/usr/local/bin/spbcopy`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >$HOME/.pastebin
```

On you OSX create `/usr/local/bin/spbpaste`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $* 'cat .pastebin; >$_'
```

Copy data to clipboard using:

```
user@remote.host$ echo "foo" | spbcopy
```

And paste data from clipboard using:

```
osx$ spbpaste user@remote.host
```

You can probably use named pipe on remote host and make the data copied to local clipboard automatically by running some command in background, but it makes it just more complex to setup.