# Copy interactive command outputs from Terminal to MacOS clipboard programmatically

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, clipboard

Developing [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/398932/copy-terminal-output-to-mac-clipboard), which offers a way to copy a given line from standard output to MacOS clipboard – I wonder if there's a way to do the same for interactive commands?
For example:

```
~ bc -l
>>> 123+4
46
>>> 56*78
4368
```

– is there a way to run `bc -l` so that after `12+34↵` – the value `46` would be in MacOS clipboard, and after `56*78↵` – clipboard would contain `4368`?